# mysql 'as' repated

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

The 1st piece of code works fine and gives me the results I need.
what I want to do now is to have it return 3 number values on the 'as num'
for 3 different values on the 'as num' for 3 different where on the same column

```
        SELECT COUNT(garage_list.account_id) as num, 
        garage_list.account_id, 
        garage_list.tank_id,
        player_list.clan,
        player_list.nickname,
        tank_list.level
    FROM garage_list 
        RIGHT JOIN player_list ON garage_list.account_id = player_list.account_id 
        RIGHT JOIN tank_list ON garage_list.tank_id = tank_list.tank_id

      where tank_list.level='8' 

      and player_list.clan = 'bad-1'
          GROUP BY account_id
```

above works

need to have a returned value for each of the " where tank_list.level='??' "

```
SELECT COUNT(garage_list.account_id) as num, 
        garage_list.account_id, 
        garage_list.tank_id,
        player_list.clan,
        player_list.nickname,
        tank_list.level
    FROM garage_list 
        RIGHT JOIN player_list ON garage_list.account_id = player_list.account_id 
        RIGHT JOIN tank_list ON garage_list.tank_id = tank_list.tank_id


      where tank_list.level='6'  //return a value for this
      where tank_list.level='8'  //return a value for this
      where tank_list.level='10'  //return a value for this

      and player_list.clan = 'bad-1'

      GROUP BY account_id
```

Comment: **`WHERE tank_list.level IN ('6', '8' ,'10')`** or join your where with AND, also your grouping is incorrect

Comment: Move some WHERE conditions to ON clauses to get true RIGHT JOIN behavior. (As it is now, you get inner join result in some cases...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a conditional COUNT using a CASE:

```
SELECT COUNT(case when tank_list.level='6' then garage_list.account_id end) as num1,
       COUNT(case when tank_list.level='8' then garage_list.account_id end) as num2,
       COUNT(case when tank_list.level='10' then garage_list.account_id end) as num3, 
        garage_list.account_id, 
        garage_list.tank_id,
        player_list.clan,
        player_list.nickname,
        tank_list.level
    FROM garage_list 
        RIGHT JOIN player_list ON garage_list.account_id = player_list.account_id 
        RIGHT JOIN tank_list ON garage_list.tank_id = tank_list.tank_id


      where tank_list.level in ('6','8','10')

      and player_list.clan = 'bad-1'

      GROUP BY account_id
```

And you need to check if your Outer Join logic is correct.